# How to use Itext7 SVG as Element?

Tags: itext7

I found some examples in the Wiki on how to include SVGs on a page, but it seems that this is disjunct from the layout.
What I want to do is something like this:

```
Table table = new Table(1)
table.addHeaderCell( Cell().add( SvgConverter.drawAsBlockElement( svgData ) ) )
```

Of course the `drawAsBlockElement` method does not exist (yet?).
Is there any simple way to achieve something similar to this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems we can use `PdfFormXObject` to create an actual iText7 image element from an SVG-file.

```
new Image(
  SvgConverter.convertToXObject(
    new FileInputStream( new File(filename) ),
    pdfDocument
)
```